# Customizable, adoptive graph drawing JS library

Tags: library, javascript, graphs, drawing

I'm not very familiar with graph drawing libraries, but I have a specific task to achieve, so wanted to ask maybe someone knows proper library, which could fit my needs.

Here is an example of the graph I need to draw:

[image]

The lines and dots can be drawn with most of libraries, but with which I could add a background to specific part of the containing grid?

I need to add another color to one of the grid columns when user click on the dot of the graph line.

Maybe someone knows the library, which could be used for this specific behavior?

Answer (score 2):

[Essential Chart for JS](http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/azure/chart/line) supports customizing the background of a portion of the chart using Strip lines. [Live Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/jr8x19vz/33/) Click on any point to see the strip line. The whole product suite is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program

[image: Screenshot]

-Davis (Syncfusion)